# Proper way to indentify uniquely a post in WordPress at database level

Tags: wordpress

A given **post** or **page** become a new record in the table `wp_posts` with a new `ID` every time a change is made to the post (or page).

Said that the `ID` cannot be used to identify a given post.

I could use the `post_title` but this may be edited.

Should I then use `post_name`?

I'm not sure what `post_name` represents in the WordPress logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ID is a unique number assigned to each post or page when it's created. The ID never changes for a specific post, regardless of any edits or revisions made to it. It's a reliable way to uniquely identify a post. However, as you noted, each revision also gets its own ID, which can be confusing if you're looking at the database directly.

Comment: you wrote `The ID never changes for a specific post` but then `each revision also gets its own ID` - so the first statement is false. You didn't asnwer the question!

Comment: You're wrong, post and page IDs are unique, revisions have a different post_type. Revisions are stored as children of their associated posts.
Official documentation: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/revisions/

Comment: ok, I understand now. Even if revisions are made (that generate a new record in the `wp_posts` table) the post maintain the original `ID` Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In WordPress, each post is uniquely identified by a numeric identifier by the `post ID`.

but you can create a custom meta field for a unique identification number in WordPress, you can use the `add_post_meta()` function.

```
$unique_id = uniqid('custom_prefix_', true);

// Add the unique ID as post meta
add_post_meta($post_id, '_unique_id', $unique_id, true);
```

`uniqid('custom_prefix_', true)` generates a unique ID based on the current timestamp and a more entropy value (using true as the second parameter). You can customize the prefix and the uniqueness requirements based on your needs